# Why can't I find System.Text.RegularExpressions when using Mono in Linux?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I'm attempting to use Mono and Monodevelop (the IDE) to code a C# project in Ubuntu.

Everything is working apart from the fact that the System.Text.RegularExpressions (Package?) is not found.  The only relevant thing I have found on the interwebs is [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mono/+bug/124857)

There appears to be a solution of sorts posted, but I don't understand.  Please help :)

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a link to the solution you want explained.

Comment: From the link it looks like something to do with dll references in the compiler command line. Can you post the command line and the actual output of the compiler?

Comment: Where would I find should information?  Currently I am using a standard package install of Mono and MonoDevelop.  I haven't changed / seen any compiler command line arguments.  As for output, the exact message is in the link I posted.  Many thanks :)

Comment: MonoDevelop invokes the mono c# compiler which is a command line tool. The command line to be executed and the output should be displayed in an output window. I haven't used MD for a while but there should be a menu item or an option to display the compiler output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MonoDevelop, right click on References and add a reference to the `System` assembly.

You could use `gmcs -r System *.cs` to compile from command line.

Answer (score 2):

Same here in VS2010. Just add a reference to System if Assembly is missing.